# xmpp jappix client : chat message not receive when user is idle stage

Tags: xmpp, openfire, jappix

I am using openfire server with jappix client. When the user is an idle stage message is not receiving. When user is active on browser window the pending messages are delivered. Be any one having any idea about this? please help me...

Comment: probably the jappix client set the status of the client as "not available" when is not focus.

Comment: No user status is not changed . Its available, but http bind call is not going, When browser is active http bind call is continuously send....